# Accessing youtube video stream map (python)

Tags: python, url, download, youtube

I'm trying to write a python script that will download a youtube video, using this line of code for getting the download url:

```
download_url = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id={0}&t={1}&fmt=22&asv=2".format(video_id, token_value)
```

(video_id and token_values being info I've got from parsing youtube video url)
but this keeps downloading empty file.

Since this method is old, is there now some other form of getting download url for youtube videos?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python  
This might help!

Comment: I found couple of posts where people claim downloading youtube videos this way isn't possible anymore, so new solution would be accessing stream maps directly through info given in youtube url. Does anyone know what would be the best approach for getting to stream maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem (to some extent) in the meantime. I just had to access youtube video stream map and grab one of the URLs stored there and download the file. However, this works only on videos that don't have their signature encrypted. I'm still working on a solution for videos with encrypted signatures.